# How to get special part of string using java streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have file abbreviations.txt where I have special infos:

**Example abbreviations.txt :**

```
PCAP_Personal Computer_Apple
NBHP_NoteBook_Hewlett Packard
TVSG_Televisor_Samsung
```

and I need to get all brand names into new List String. Im trying use this:

```
 Stream<String> abbreviations = Files.lines(Paths.get("src/main/resources/raceData/abbreviations.txt"))
            .flatMap(Pattern.compile("_")::splitAsStream);
    List<String> dates = abbreviations.collect(Collectors.toList());
    dates.forEach(System.out::println);
```

But as List I get:

```
PCAP_Personal Computer
Apple
TVSG_Televisor
Samsung
NBHP_NoteBook
Hewlett Packard
```

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Answer (score 5):

`splitAsStream`?

That's not necessary. Just use

```
.map(line -> line.split("_")[2])
```

This of course assumes that all lines have the correct format. You could of course filter out malformed lines, for example, using

```java
.map(line -> line.split("_"))
.filter(parts -> parts.length >= 3)
.map(parts -> parts[2])
```

You could then put it into an array, using `toArray`. However, I recommend to use a `List` instead, because by far the most implementations are way more powerful. You can do so using a `Collector`:

```java
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If we base to *I need to get all brand names* your solution is totally correct.

Comment: is it possible to add this values to an array?

Comment: @marzocchi in that case you can just use   `.toArray(String[]::new);` after the map method to convert the stream to array. see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64376869/2815227

Comment: I would, however, recommend using a `List` instead of an array, as a list is more flexible and more powerful at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If the brand names are what is after the last `'_'`

```
    String s = "PCAP_Personal Computer_Apple\n" +
            "NBHP_NoteBook_Hewlett Packard\n" +
            "TVSG_Televisor_Samsung" ;

    Stream<String> abbreviations = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\n"));
    List<String> brandNames  =  abbreviations
            .map(abbr -> abbr.substring(abbr.lastIndexOf('_') + 1))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    brandNames.forEach(System.out::println);
```

will print you

```
Apple
Hewlett Packard
Samsung
```

If you need them to be an array, just use

```
            String[]  brandNames  =  abbreviations
                .map(abbr -> abbr.substring(abbr.lastIndexOf('_') + 1))
                .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It just deletes everything up to and including the last underscore.

```
String[] lines = { "PCAP_Personal Computer_Apple",
        "NBHP_NoteBook_Hewlett Packard",
        "TVSG_Televisor_Samsung",
        "And_more_than_two_underscores_IBM" };

List<String> vendors = Arrays.stream(lines)
        .map(str -> str.replaceAll(".*(?>_)", ""))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
vendors.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
Apple
Hewlett Packard
Samsung
IBM
```